# Is there any performance difference when passing objects in function parameter based on object size?

Tags: php

I have class A, B, C, D

```
class A {
   public $b;
   public $c;
   public $d;
   // Other properties

   function __construct() {
       $this->b = new B();
       $this->c = new C();
       $this->d = new D();
    }
   function process() {
       $x = new ExternalClass($this->b, $this->c, $this->d)
       // $x = new ExternalClass($this)
   }
   // other functions. 
 }
```

Here, is there any performance deference passing parameter as $this instead of $this->b, $this->c, $this->d ? 
Later, i may need to send more objects $this->e, $this->f etc. Instead of passing each object variables,  if i passing $this object I can access whatever objects i want. But I want know is there any performance issue involved in this.

Comment: It will only be an issue when you do it a couple of 100'000 times.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you really don't need to worry about the performance. You never measure difference in real world application.

What I would be woried much more is your implementation. Read something about [Dependency Injection (DI)](https://doc.nette.org/en/2.4/dependency-injection) and try decouple your application to more classes using [Single Responsibility Principle (SRP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).